Removing Labels from LV95 Swiss Topographic Layer
I’m looking to modify the background layer named "LV95 Swiss Topographic (with Contours and Hillshade)" in ArcGIS Pro by removing the labels. I came across a suggestion in the metadata to use the ArcGIS Vector Tile Style Editor for this purpose. However, I'm having trouble loading the layer in the editor.
Could you guide me on how to make this change? Is there another method or a workaround to achieve this?
Data: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03af6dc44c1e4c948eb87bbaef248f7a

I may be wrong but looking at the basemaps in ArcGIS Vector Tile Style Editor the LV95 basemap appears to be very similar if not the same as the World Topographic Map (with Contours and Hillshade) basemap. I was able to turn off road and building labels quite easily.

